# mdadm RAID5 to RAID6 migration thrown exceptions, access to data lost

Tags: debian, mdadm, software-raid, raid5

After a dozen of hours waiting for my array reshape to move on I think it's finally the right time to ask you for some advice.

Recently I bought 4th WD Red 4TB drive to migrate my 3-disk RAID5 setup to RAID6. All disks are WD Red 4TB, so I have 8TB of usable space. The space occupation is right now at 50%.

I've installed the 4th disk and added it to the `/dev/md0` with the following command:

```bsh
mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdf1
```

Then I've started the RAID5 to RAID6 migration with the following command:

```bsh
mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --level=6 --raid-disk=4
```

The grow operation started and initially the speed was pretty decent compared to what I've found over the Internet ([example](https://www.reddit.com/r/DataHoarder/comments/70p5iw/md_raid_reshape_stuck_advice/)), but after 12 hours I've reached 44k/sec and right it's 10k/sec. The `cat /proc/mdstat` looks as follows:

```bsh
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md0 : active raid6 sdf1[6] sdd1[4] sda1[5] sde1[3]
      7813771264 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 18 [4/3] [UUU_]
      [>....................]  reshape =  0.1% (4931044/3906885632) finish=6498319.2min speed=10K/sec
      bitmap: 8/30 pages [32KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

The reshape process didn't move from `4931044` for 5-6 hours in the time of writing this question.

The disk layout of the system i'm working on is the following (a dump from `lsblk`):

```bsh
NAME               MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                  8:0    0  3.7T  0 disk
└─sda1               8:1    0  3.7T  0 part
  └─md0              9:0    0  7.3T  0 raid6
    └─vg_data-data 254:0    0  7.3T  0 lvm   /data
sdb                  8:16   0 55.9G  0 disk
├─sdb1               8:17   0 53.6G  0 part  /
├─sdb2               8:18   0    1K  0 part
└─sdb5               8:21   0  2.3G  0 part  [SWAP]
sdc                  8:32   0  1.8T  0 disk
└─sdc1               8:33   0  1.8T  0 part  /mnt/Backup-usb
sdd                  8:48   0  3.7T  0 disk
└─sdd1               8:49   0  3.7T  0 part
  └─md0              9:0    0  7.3T  0 raid6
    └─vg_data-data 254:0    0  7.3T  0 lvm   /data
sde                  8:64   0  3.7T  0 disk
└─sde1               8:65   0  3.7T  0 part
  └─md0              9:0    0  7.3T  0 raid6
    └─vg_data-data 254:0    0  7.3T  0 lvm   /data
sdf                  8:80   0  3.7T  0 disk
└─sdf1               8:81   0  3.7T  0 part
  └─md0              9:0    0  7.3T  0 raid6
    └─vg_data-data 254:0    0  7.3T  0 lvm   /data
```

The `/dev/md0` is mounted on `/data`
In order to speed up the migration I've adjusted the following parameters after the reshape was running:

```bsh
sysctl -w dev.raid.speed_limit_min=100000
sysctl -w dev.raid.speed_limit_max=500000
echo 4096 > /sys/block/md0/md/stripe_cache_size
blockdev --setra 65536 /dev/md0
```

I've also issued `echo max > /sys/block/md0/md/sync_max` two times in order to see if it won't affect the speed positively.

My problem is that currently, the reshape process seems to be stuck. If `dmesg | grep md0` is issued, the following problems are reported:

```bsh
[58169.337512] md/raid:md0: raid level 6 active with 3 out of 4 devices, algorithm 18
[58169.805197] md: reshape of RAID array md0
[58169.805201] md: minimum _guaranteed_  speed: 1000 KB/sec/disk.
[58169.805203] md: using maximum available idle IO bandwidth (but not more than 200000 KB/sec) for reshape.
[58169.805208] md: using 128k window, over a total of 3906885632k.
[58359.078753] md/raid:md0: read error corrected (8 sectors at 9990072 on sdd1)
[58359.078758] md/raid:md0: read error corrected (8 sectors at 9990080 on sdd1)
[58359.078761] md/raid:md0: read error corrected (8 sectors at 9990088 on sdd1)
[58359.078763] md/raid:md0: read error corrected (8 sectors at 9990096 on sdd1)
[58359.078773] md/raid:md0: read error corrected (8 sectors at 9990104 on sdd1)
[58359.078774] md/raid:md0: read error corrected (8 sectors at 9990112 on sdd1)
[58359.078775] md/raid:md0: read error corrected (8 sectors at 9990120 on sdd1)
[58359.078780] md/raid:md0: read error corrected (8 sectors at 9990128 on sdd1)
[58359.078781] md/raid:md0: read error corrected (8 sectors at 9990136 on sdd1)
[58359.078791] md/raid:md0: read error corrected (8 sectors at 9990072 on sda1)
[58666.606583]       Tainted: G         C    3.16.0-4-amd64 #1
[58666.606721]       Tainted: G         C    3.16.0-4-amd64 #1
[58666.606825]       Tainted: G         C    3.16.0-4-amd64 #1
[58666.606948]       Tainted: G         C    3.16.0-4-amd64 #1
[58666.607039]       Tainted: G         C    3.16.0-4-amd64 #1
[58666.607148] INFO: task md0_reshape:17403 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[58666.607168]       Tainted: G         C    3.16.0-4-amd64 #1
[58666.607206] md0_reshape     D ffff880216d33748     0 17403      2 0x00000000
[58666.607225]  [<ffffffffa0333cf2>] ? is_mddev_idle+0xd2/0x140 [md_mod]
[58666.607229]  [<ffffffffa0336df4>] ? md_do_sync+0x944/0xd80 [md_mod]
[58666.607233]  [<ffffffffa0333b87>] ? md_thread+0x107/0x120 [md_mod]
[58666.607238]  [<ffffffffa0333a80>] ? md_stop+0x40/0x40 [md_mod]
[58786.578974]       Tainted: G         C    3.16.0-4-amd64 #1
[58786.579191]       Tainted: G         C    3.16.0-4-amd64 #1
[58786.579342]       Tainted: G         C    3.16.0-4-amd64 #1
[58786.579508] INFO: task md0_reshape:17403 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[58786.579545]       Tainted: G         C    3.16.0-4-amd64 #1
[58786.579612] md0_reshape     D ffff880216d33748     0 17403      2 0x00000000
[58786.579639]  [<ffffffffa0333cf2>] ? is_mddev_idle+0xd2/0x140 [md_mod]
[58786.579644]  [<ffffffffa0336df4>] ? md_do_sync+0x944/0xd80 [md_mod]
[58786.579651]  [<ffffffffa0333b87>] ? md_thread+0x107/0x120 [md_mod]
[58786.579658]  [<ffffffffa0333a80>] ? md_stop+0x40/0x40 [md_mod]
```

Moreover, I cannot access `/data` contents. If I issue `cd /data` everything seems to be fine, but if I list the contents the command `ls` literally hangs returning no result and forcing me to kill ssh session to the server.

I'm using `mdadm - v3.3.2 - 21st August 2014` running on Debian `Linux debnas 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1 (2016-12-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

The output from `iostat -k 1 2` is the following:

```bsh
Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 (debnas)   09/02/2019      _x86_64_        (4 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           1.25    0.00   15.25   36.91    0.00   46.59

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
sdb               4.42        16.33        37.55    2191851    5038772
sda              60.00     29162.00        78.31 3913364324   10508977
sdc               0.11         0.15         0.00      19751         40
sdd              59.64        40.30     29191.39    5408213 3917308368
sde              59.97     29162.68        77.94 3913455394   10459365
sdf               0.12         0.03        36.79       4157    4936637
md0               1.79         7.45        75.01     999197   10066300
dm-0              1.71         7.44        75.01     998645   10066300

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.50    0.00   25.00   74.50    0.00    0.00

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
sdb               0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
sda               0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
sdc               0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
sdd               0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
sde               0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
sdf               0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
md0               0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-0              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
```

UPDATE 201909021128:
As dmesg reports read errors on `sda` and `sdd` I'm publishing the complete output of `smartctl -a` for both drives.

```bsh
user@debnas:/home/user# smartctl -a /dev/sda
smartctl 6.4 2014-10-07 r4002 [x86_64-linux-3.16.0-4-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-14, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Red (AF)
Device Model:     WDC WD40EFRX-68N32N0
Serial Number:    WD-WCC7K0YEYNV9
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 2663bb359
Firmware Version: 82.00A82
User Capacity:    4,000,787,030,016 bytes [4.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Sep  2 11:27:38 2019 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (45360) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 482) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x303d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   225   163   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       3741
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       66
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       183
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       66
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       20
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       52
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   113   105   000    Old_age   Always       -       37
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

```bsh
user@debnas:/home/user# smartctl -a /dev/sdd
smartctl 6.4 2014-10-07 r4002 [x86_64-linux-3.16.0-4-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-14, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Red (AF)
Device Model:     WDC WD40EFRX-68N32N0
Serial Number:    WD-WCC7K2HNS0C0
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 211682e4b
Firmware Version: 82.00A82
User Capacity:    4,000,787,030,016 bytes [4.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Sep  2 11:30:55 2019 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (43920) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 466) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x303d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   253   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   228   200   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       3583
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       8
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       38
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       8
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       6
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       6
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   113   104   000    Old_age   Always       -       37
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Update 201909021143:
It seems that the `md0_raid` process is consuming all the CPU resources. After Issuing `ps aux | grep md0` I can see the CPU utilization is 99.7% and the reshape is not consuming CPU at all:

```bsh
root     17401 99.7  0.0      0     0 ?        R    Sep01 1348:35 [md0_raid6]
root     17403  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Sep01   0:04 [md0_reshape]
```

These are the last lines of `dmesg`:

```bsh
[58786.579309] INFO: task postgres:5070 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[58786.579342]       Tainted: G         C    3.16.0-4-amd64 #1
[58786.579371] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[58786.579409] postgres        D ffff8801e2860ff8     0  5070   3818 0x00000000
[58786.579412]  ffff8801e2860ba0 0000000000000082 0000000000012f40 ffff8801b4767fd8
[58786.579414]  0000000000012f40 ffff8801e2860ba0 ffff88021fa137f0 ffff88021fdbf578
[58786.579416]  0000000000000002 ffffffff8113eb70 ffff8801b4767ba0 0000000000000000
[58786.579419] Call Trace:
[58786.579421]  [<ffffffff8113eb70>] ? wait_on_page_read+0x60/0x60
[58786.579424]  [<ffffffff815178e9>] ? io_schedule+0x99/0x120
[58786.579426]  [<ffffffff8113eb7a>] ? sleep_on_page+0xa/0x10
[58786.579429]  [<ffffffff81517c6c>] ? __wait_on_bit+0x5c/0x90
[58786.579432]  [<ffffffff8113e976>] ? wait_on_page_bit+0xc6/0xd0
[58786.579434]  [<ffffffff810a95f0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x30/0x30
[58786.579437]  [<ffffffff8114dc7a>] ? pagevec_lookup_entries+0x1a/0x30
[58786.579440]  [<ffffffff8114e662>] ? truncate_inode_pages_range+0x302/0x5a0
[58786.579449]  [<ffffffffa02efb67>] ? __ext4_journal_stop+0x37/0xa0 [ext4]
[58786.579457]  [<ffffffffa02d075b>] ? ext4_rename+0x11b/0x660 [ext4]
[58786.579461]  [<ffffffff811d1212>] ? __inode_wait_for_writeback+0x72/0xc0
[58786.579464]  [<ffffffff812037f8>] ? __dquot_initialize+0x28/0x1c0
[58786.579467]  [<ffffffff810a95f0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x30/0x30
[58786.579475]  [<ffffffffa02c79f7>] ? ext4_evict_inode+0x127/0x4e0 [ext4]
[58786.579478]  [<ffffffff811c475c>] ? evict+0xac/0x170
[58786.579481]  [<ffffffff811c0548>] ? __dentry_kill+0x168/0x1d0
[58786.579484]  [<ffffffff811c064e>] ? dput+0x9e/0x170
[58786.579486]  [<ffffffff811b8588>] ? SYSC_renameat2+0x498/0x530
[58786.579491]  [<ffffffff811719a5>] ? vm_munmap+0x45/0x50
[58786.579494]  [<ffffffff8151adcd>] ? system_call_fast_compare_end+0x10/0x15
```

My questions are the following:

1. What to do in order to move the reshape process forward?
2. Do you think the data on the `md0` is safe?
3. How to access the data on `md0` if I cannot `cd` to it?
4. What are those stack traces in the `dmesg` output?

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you check `smartctl -a` for all drives regarding the reported read errors? also dmesg in full without grep might have interesting additional info regarding those. if those drives actually have problems, maybe you have to ddrescue and cross fingers here.

Comment: @frostschutz as requested I've updated the question with `smartctl -a` for `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdd` reported by dmesg. To be honest I don't expect the drives to be failed or damaged as they are completely new devices: before RAID5 to RAID6 migration the 3-disk RAID5 array had two disks with `current_pending_sector`. I've bought one disk and rebuilt the array with two working disks and one with `current_pending_sector` errors. After that, I've purchased two more disks, rebulit the RAID5 array once more to replace the last failing drive and performed the migration to RAID6.

Comment: @frostschutz ... in other words the read errors may come from the time when the RAID5 array was running with two disks with `current_pending_sector` errors. This is just my guess, but after a single rebuild process when the RAID5 disk was replaced I've lost a single 4GB file with the error that It cannot be read.

Comment: I see you've already posted this to the linux-raid mailing list. It may be the better platform for individual support. Somehow your kernel got stuck in a bug, maybe related to those pending sectors, maybe not. Reboot probably unavoidable at this point. Some of those bugs were fixed more recently, so if you're sure the drives only had harmless problems, you could also try with current (Sept 01) archlinux live cd or similar. If data very important, not wrong to pull a ddrescue of whatever you have now to a set of new drives anyway, and then use overlays for experiments. Best of luck.

Comment: @frostschutz If I reboot (I won't do it know, but would like to know already), would I lost the data?

Comment: could go either way (like a power loss)